Can we prove or disprove that Humanoids and Giants are defined by their Size Categories?
If we take a look at the Humanoids in the Monster Manual we see that all of them are either creature size Medium or Small. I personally presume this is because Humanoids are what most player characters are and playable races are by design always small or medium.
We can find a similiar situation if we look at Giants. All of them are of the sizes Large, Huge or Gargantuan (there are no Gargantuan Giants in the MM, but there are in Glory of the Giants). One could argue, that Giants are Humanoids who are to big to be classified as such. The introduction of the MM even says "Giants tower over humans and their kind [i.e humanoids]".
This gets even more interesting if we look at two tall races that are supposedly related to Giants: the Firbolgs and the Goliaths. Neither of them have the Giant creature type, as both are humanoids, be it as player characters or as monster statblocks. And it would seem that this is because they are of size category Medium, a category that Giants are supposedly banned from. And then if we look at the Half-Ogre, we get the same thing in reverse, this Half-Humanoid & Half-Giant, is still considered a Giant, and it would seem to be because it boasts the Large creature size.
Regardless of the reasoning for this, the game heavily implies that Humanoids and Giants can only exist in specific size categories and not in any others, Small and Medium for the former and Large, Huge and Gargantuan for the latter. However as far as I could find, this fact is never outright stated as such. The closest thing I could find are the descriptions of the creature types in the third Edition SRD. Where it says that humanoids "usually are Small or Medium-size" and Giants are "usually of at least Large size".
The word 'usually' here intrigues me, as it suggest there might be Humanoids and Giants that defy these Size Categories and would therefore disprove my theory of them being mechanically defined by their sizes. Which is why I am asking: Can anyone tell me any prove or disprove on the implication that the Humanoid and Giant creature types are limited to certain size categories?
This might be:

Any official statements that outright state that this is or is not the case.*
Any Humanoid or Giant Statblocks or Playable Races that defy these rules.**

These preferably from official sources pertaining 5E, if not than I would also accept something from an earlier edition of the game or officially promoted 5E Fan Content (e.g. Kobold Press).

*Not counting of course the aforementioned descriptions in the MM and the 3E SRD, as these both seem to kinda dodge the question and don't answer it directly, leaving us in the dark. The MM one being more of a description than a rule and the 3E one sounding just vague enough for them to leave the possibility open to defy these rules if they want to in the future.
**Of course eligible creatures would only include average adults of their respective races, as we can assume that humanoids babies would be classified as tiny humanoids and we learn from Glory of the Giants that children of true giants are medium-sized Giants. And we of course must also limit it to Creatures in their default state, unaffected by Magic or other Abilities that change their Size. As we know that both the Runecarver Fighter and Path of the Giant Barbarian can increase their sizes to large and beyond, while still being humanoids and so can a medium Wizard that casts Enlarge on themself.

I don't normally agree with people who ask this, but what problem are you trying to solve?

@SeriousBri Whether or not it would be within the guidelines set by WotC to create custom Statblocks that defy these rules. In the case of wanting to stay as close to the offical sources as possible.

@SeriousBri Or in other words: could WotC have just decided that Ogres/Half-Ogres are humanoids even though they are Large and that Firborgs are Giants even though they are medium or would they then have broken an unspoken rule, which we can reverse engineer.

@TreeSpawned The enlarge question should be fine as a question, if you are unsure you can workshop it in [chat] or on [meta] You hunch is right, though. Objects can not be unwilling, so there is no Con save for them, they just get enlarged.

@NobodytheHobgoblin Fancy seeing you here. Gotta tell you it was your comment where you mistook Ogres for Humanoids, that got me started on the whole rabbit hole, that lead to this question. Anyway thanks for the suggestions, I must admit I did not consider any of these places to spitball my question. I guess though I am not going to ask it now anyway, as I already have an answer and am really not in the mood for another potentially downvoted question right now. I kinda think my question sounds stupid if I think about it, now that I know the answer.

@TreeSpawned Yeah, it can be pretty rough in here. People don't like a question, they are quick to downvote it, as there is no cost to it. FWIW I thought the question was interesting, and am one of your upvotes.

Is it worth mentioning that even in real-world mythology (I'm thinking of Norse mythology specifically) the term giant (also "troll", both used to gloss "jötunn", which becomes "eotan" and eventually "ettin" in English!) can mean a creature of any size, or at least of a size comparable to the Norse gods (who are usually assumed to be human-sized).  It's a bit of an odd choice, historically!

This search at D&D Beyond yields five large humanoids (and zero huge or gargantuan humanoids):

Deformed Duergar
Ghald (a named sahaguin)
Lizardfolk Render
Sahuagin Baron
Sundeth

This search at D&D Beyond yields four medium giants, two of which are children:

Cloud Giant Child
Giant Child
Irda Seeker
Irda Veil Keeper


Man you are correct and I even read the Irda Statblocks last year. I see that I have messed up here and that I could have just easily looked this, but it appears I was so sure of my assumptions that I didn't even think of it. I was probably suffering from a severe case of confirmation bias. I even have my own Spreadsheet of Statblocks and had both the Irda's and the Sahuagin Baron in there, but for some reason refused to take a look.

Have you considered asking meta.rpg.stackexchange.com for feedback on the question?

The Sahuaguin Baron from the Monster Manual is a Large Humanoid. I know of no official statblocks for a Medium/Small/Tiny Giant.
However, creature types in D&D 5e do not have inherent rules, as stated in the MM. There is no restriction on having a magically cursed race of tiny giants or oversized orcs.

You are correct, and it would appear I have made a grievous error in the very foundation of my question, as the solution was right there for me in Monster Manual. Should I now delete my question as it is inherently wrong in and of itself?

@TreeSpawned it is best to leave questions be, other people can still learn from them

@TreeSpawned Your question has an upvoted answer, so it cannot be deleted.

@ThomasMarkov I upvoted it myself as it was correct and helpful

+1 "Creature types do not have inherent rules" this is the 'proof' requested.

@Kirt I am aware of the clarification that creature types do not have rules. This question however does not pertain to rules, I am asking about the design principles behind these types.

@TreeSpawned "Can anyone tell me any prove or disprove on the implication that the Humanoid and Giant creature types are limited to certain size categories?" Answered.  "I personally presume this is because Humanoids are what most player characters are and playable races are by design always small or medium. "  Vague, designer intent, and not emphasized in the question.  I suggest you ask a separate question about why PC's are Medium / Small if that is what you want (and if it has not already been asked and answered).

@Kirt Correct, my question is answered. But I do not need a follow-up-question as I don't want to ask why PCs are always medium and small, I just extrapolated, that that might be a reason why the Humanoids Monsters I knew off, were always these sizes. I said "Regardless of the reasoning for this..." and then explained what I actually wanted to know: Whether or not Creatures of these two Types only exist within the Size Categories i could find. i was looking for the design guidelines and their examples set by WotC, the reasons for these were second hand to me.
